# Getting Input Key for Atbash Cipher

Tags: c++, performance

An [Atbash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atbash) cipher is a simple substitution cipher wherein a key is used to determine what letters to swap, for example:

```
Original alphabet: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Substitute (key):  zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
Original message:  hello world
Altered message:   svool dliow
```

In my program, I get the key by printing the original letter, and then getting the letter that is to substitute it, and adding it to a `key` string, for example:

```
a = <user input>
b = <user input>
c = <user input>
...
```

Here is the simple code that I use for it:

```cpp
std::cout << "Key:\n";
std::string key;

for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
    std::cout << static_cast<char>('a' + i) << " = ";
    char inputChar;

    std::cin >> inputChar;
    key += inputChar;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

How can I improve this code?

Comment: I think the `std::cin.ignore();` and  `std::cin.clear();` are superfluous.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it is implementation defined if they are superfluous, but in practice (windows-linux), yeah, pretty much.

Comment: @Incomputable Not really _implementation defined_. Reading a sequence of `char`s,- whitespace delimited or not -, should work fine in any implementation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I meant the ignore-clear-flush sequence. It is implementation defined for `cin` and `cout` that they actually ignore-clear-flush on death

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're right. Instead of using ignore-clear-flush, I replaced it with `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');`.

Comment: @Idempotence I don't think you should need that at all. Does something go wrong with your code leaving that out?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah, if something like `aaaaaaa` is entered in the first input, it acts like they tried to enter multiple consecutive inputs.

Comment: @Idempotence And you want to interact with single character inputs confirmed by [ENTER] only?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yup, so adding the ignore fixes problems where it isn't a single character.

Comment: @Idempotence For better UI experience you should let know the user what is expected and what will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I improve this code?

Fix a bug ;). At the moment, one can accidentally enter the same character twice, e.g.:

```
a = a
b = a
c = a
...
z = a
```

Unless you want to allow that usage, you probably want to check which characters are already used:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
    std::cout << static_cast<char>('a' + i) << " = ";
    char inputChar;

    std::cin >> inputChar;

    if(key.find(inputChar) == std::string::npos){
        key += inputChar;
    } else {
        // yell at user!
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

Also, if you know the size of the `std::string` in advance, you can speed up append operations (such as `+=`) with `reserve`:

```
std::string key;

key.reserve(26);

// ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add a test for such an error. You're answer covers it most completely. I also changed `key += inputChar` to `key += tolower(inputChar)` because entering capital letters breaks the `find(inputChar)` part.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it is very inadvisable to use the `+=` operator with strings, because it's slow and it requires the string to be relocated in the memory. This isn't much of a problem with higher-level languages like Python, but with C and also Java, it's not a good idea, and it's not good practice. Since you know that there are 26 letters in the alphabet, you can make a length 26 array to store the key instead. Otherwise, the rest of the code looks good! :)

Comment: You could simply call `reserve` on the allocated string object to avoid unnecessary allocations. Then, using `+=` would be totally fine and entail no performance penalty.

Comment: Amortized constant doesn't mean free, @zeta. You have to understand what is actually going on under the hood. It performs an allocation and copy if there is not enough space available in the backing buffer. It grows the buffer by a constant multiplier (1.5x or 2x are common for most implementations), with the idea that you won't need to allocate additional space each time you append, which is where the "amortized" part comes in. But allocations still have to happen, and you won't necessarily benefit from the amortization. Reserving enough space in advance is always the most performant choice.